# Counting how many times each unique element appeared in `select` query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have a MySQL database with million of records, table is well indexed. Below is the table structure.

[image]

I ran the below code in my table.

```
SELECT `iwebs` FROM `wordstable` WHERE `iwebs` LIKE 'a1' or `iwebs` LIKE 'a2' or `iwebs` LIKE 'a3' or `iwebs` LIKE 'a4' or `iwebs` LIKE 'a5' or `iwebs` LIKE 'a6' or `iwebs` LIKE 'a7' or `iwebs` LIKE 'a8' or `iwebs` LIKE 'a9' or `iwebs` LIKE 'a10'
```

Now this code generates the below output (small part of output is displayed).

[image]

However, this is not what I need. what I need is a key-value pair where it displays how many times each individual element appeared in the result. Something like

```
[a1,400]
[a2,100]
[a3,5]
[a5,500]
........
```

In the above example, the first item in each bracket means the individual element appeared in the `select` query and the second item means the number of times it appeared.

In other words, it means "a1 appeared 400 times in select query", "a2 appeared 100 times in select query", "a3 appeared 5 times in select query" and "a5 appeared 500 times in select query" and so on.

How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: This is a simple count/group by

Comment: @paqogomez: No, the normal count and groupby will return how many times each element present in the "table". But have a look at my query, I am seeking for set of "items" using the `like` keyword, I only need to know how many times they appear in the "search".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well with a bit of thinking you should be able to combine the solution from @Ilesh with your request:

```
SELECT iwebs, COUNT(iwebs) FROM wordstable WHERE iwebs IN ('a1','a2','a3','a4') GROUP BY iwebs
```

Comment: And if you wanna have excatly your output, try SELECT CAST(CONCAT('[',iwebs,',',COUNT(iwebs),']') AS CHAR(64) AS count FROM wordstable WHERE iwebs IN ('a1','a2','a3','a4') GROUP BY iwebs

Comment: Yeah your code worked. But what did you mean by "exactly your output" in your comment?

Comment: well you wrote you wanted to have an output like [a1,100] [a2,29]... and thats what the concat does for you.. reformat the two result columns into one with your square brackets

Comment: ah noono. I don't need the brackets. I used bracket to show "one row"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT iwebs , COUNT(iwebs) FROM wordstable GROUP BY iwebs
```

**EDIT FOR SPECIFIC REQUIREMENT**

```
SELECT iwebs , COUNT(iwebs) FROM wordstable  WHERE `iwebs` IN
```

('a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8' ,'a9' ,'a10')  GROUP BY iwebs

Comment: No, this is not what I need. This returned all the counts in the "table". But have a look at my query, I seeking for set of values, I only need to know how many times they appeared, not the entire one.

Comment: check my edits in which I add WHERE clause OR You can put same WHERE condition in 1st query as you put in your question

Comment: I did. It generated an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `iwebs` IN ('a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8' ,'a9' ,'a10')`